# AVAssetExportSession stuck (not starting) export

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

I have attempted to export videos from Photo Library, but the export callback is never executed. I periodically check the progress of the export, and the progress is always zero.

The code below works in 99.9% cases, but sometimes on some devices (absolutely randomly) it stops working and only restart of the iPhone helps.

`AVAssetExportSession.Status` always in `waiting` state

```
class FilesInteractor {
    static func tempDirectoryPath() -> String {
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
        return documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("temp") as String
    }

    static func createTempDirectory() {
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: tempDirectoryPath()) {
            try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: tempDirectoryPath(), withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        }
    }

    static func testVideoURL(name: String, ext: String = "mov") -> URL {
        createTempDirectory()
        let outputURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("test").appendingPathComponent("\(name).\(ext)", isDirectory: false)

        log.debug("Test video URL: \(outputURL)")

        return outputURL
    }
}
```

```
import AVFoundation

let asset = AVAsset()
let outputURL = FilesInteractor.testVideoURL("output")

let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1280x720)
exportSession?.outputFileType = .mov
exportSession?.outputURL = outputURL

try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputURL)
exportSession?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
    print("sometimes never calls")
})
```

Other video apps also freeze (Filto, Videoleap):

[image: Filto]

[image: Videoleap]

Comment: Do you have any information regarding the used iOS versions?

Comment: looks like it does not depend on iOS version, I saw it on different devices and different versions.

Comment: In my case the videos are saved on icloud and unloaded from device, so this does the job for me exportSession?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

Comment: I have got some problem. My opinion is problem with freezing (not starting) appears after break running of Application in Xcode. Reboot is the only solution I found

Answer (score 3):

I saw this issue a couple of times on some Github projects and usually it had something to do with how the URL was created. Not sure if the code you put in your question was just some placeholder but I think you should create a fileURL like this instead of "string".

```
var tempFileUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("temp_video_data.mp4", isDirectory: false)
tempFileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: tempFileUrl.path)
exportSession.outputURL = tempFileUrl
```

Perhaps this will fix it?

Comment: I do the same. Doesn't help

Comment: Hm too bad. Your code above doesn't show that you use'fileURLWithPath' though?

Comment: Hi, Bob. Looks like you were right, but with some amendments. Please, look at the code above. As soon as I do .appendingPathComponent("test") it freezes. Without it - all works good. The bug is fixed, but I don't understand the reason :(

Comment: @VasiliiKasnitski Hm I think it's because the final path is not correct anymore. I can't really see the full path though because you do a lot in 1 line ;) Perhaps split it up in several lines and print each url in between? Then you can probably see where it goes wrong :)

Comment: The problem goes back :(
It is an example of the output URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B9EB607F-8F6F-4E3B-A6C3-88B580B8839F/Documents/temp/last.mov
This url doesn't work and the export session is stuck...

Comment: @VasiliiKasnitski Can you try it without creating a new directory called 'temp'? And perhaps it goes wrong when there's already an existing file with the same name? Perhaps check if there's already a file called that? Let me know if any of the 2 above helps :)

Comment: 1. Yes, sure, I tried to export without creating a new directory. Also, I tried to create absolutely new folder - both didn't work.
2. "Perhaps check if there's already a file called that". Yes, but I don't check, I always remove the file before exporting.

I also created the same issue on the [Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649671) but still no answers :(

Comment: Hm too bad, not sure if I have any other ideas right now. I'll think about it some more.