# xcode hangs on video trim (infrequent and random) and also bizarrely iphone screen record hangs when in this condition

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, trim, screen-recording

iOS app enables video trimming that works perfectly most of the time (recorded videos that are local, camera roll access videos, and app screen recorded videos that are local - all see same issue).  Infrequently and randomly, get somewhere between long delay and what seems to be forever spinner on the export part of trim - never makes it to save.

Amazingly - when we are having this issue, the iphone screen recorder also hangs between a long time and likely forever (can only wait so long...). Meaning stop and instead of getting box right away saying saved and going to camera roll - neither happens for between a long time and forever.

other info:

- built stand alone app using camera roll video also hangs there when in this "state".
- I'm not sure our app causes problem.  When close app and restart - doesn't clear.  Have to restart device or sometimes wait a long time seems to clear.
- Haven't been able reproduce
- Have seen mostly on one device, but did show up on another at one point.
- Tried 3rd part app that also trims - works.  Also - iphone native camera still works.
- short videos and screen records
- if clears this state - screen recording and trim complete come through at same time.

Questions:

1. any suggested alternate settings to trim video.  3rd party works when in this state so there is a solution. Or other approaches - ffmpeg is only one I thought of but too slow.
2. is is possible for our app to be causing this problem?  Screwing up iphone screen recorder seems like tough for us to do...
3. any smoking gun on what could cause the iphone screen record save to be delayed.

Thanks for any ideas - can't find really anything on this anywhere.

Here is code that almost always works - gets stuck on "Exporting..." - if leave app and come back - says "Export Failed"

```
    if (self.phasset == nil) {
            [self trimOriginal];
            self.isExportInProgress = NO;
            return;
        }
        
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
        alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
        alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        UIAlertAction *saveAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Save as New Clip" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
            
            [self showSpinnerWithMessage:@"Exporting ..."];
            
            __weak TrimViewController *weakSelf = self;
            NSString *path = self.tempVideoPath;
            
            [self exportAsset:self.asset preset:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough completion:^(BOOL success, NSURL * _Nullable url) {
                
                __strong TrimViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;
                
                if (!strongSelf) { return; }
                
                if (!strongSelf) {
                    [strongSelf hideSpinner];

                    [Utils showAlert:strongSelf title:@"Error" message:@"Export failed"];
                    strongSelf.isExportInProgress = NO;
                    return;
                }
                
                strongSelf.spinnerLabel.text = @"Saving ...";
                
                NSURL *movieUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
                AVAsset *trimmed_asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:movieUrl];
                                        
                [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
                    [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:movieUrl];
                } completionHandler:^(BOOL saved, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                    
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        
                        strongSelf.isExportInProgress = NO;
                        
                        [strongSelf hideSpinner];
                        
                        if (error) {
                            [Utils showAlert:strongSelf title:@"Error" message:@"Video Saving Failed"];
                        } else {
                            strongSelf.saveAsNewClip = FALSE;
                            [strongSelf.delegate trimedVideoAsset:strongSelf asset:trimmed_asset];
                        }
                    });
                }];
            }];
```

Comment: It is stuck on this line of code:              [self exportAsset:self.asset preset:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough completion:^(BOOL success, NSURL * _Nullable url) {   .  Hung up when in this state : main app, stand-alone simple app, iphone screen recorder, one third party app.  Working:  a different third party app.  So there is a solution.   Have had issue with both medium quality and passthrough.  Any ideas on an alternate approach on getting through export?

Comment: this is it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58912668/avassetexportsession-stuck-not-starting-export